# Secured Socket.IO access to GCP VM.s

Tags: node.js, ssl, socket.io, google-compute-engine

I'm building a backend for a multiplayer game. It's Node.JS based, and deployed to Google Compute-Engine VMs, in a managed-instance group.
This backend manages many instances of a game, each game instances hosts a several players, and since each game instance is stateful, it should be managed on the SAME VM.

The connection flow is as follows:

1. A client opens the game page with an ID of the game instance
2. The client requests the API for an available game-server IP
3. The client then connects to the game-server DIRECTLY (not via any load balancer)

The problem is that the connection to the game-servers must be secured, and since the connection is not via a load balancer, I don't have any way to secure the connection.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: why are you not using LB and use any alternatives like openvpn/strongswan for  secure connection.

Comment: As I wrote in the question, the connection to the socket server must be direct and not via any LB. A load balancer spreads the incoming clients to server according to traffic or CPU utilization, but I need my clients to connect to specific servers in the group based on more complex application-level considerations.

Comment: Since you are not considering the usage of LB,For secure connection to a specific VM, the point-to-site vpn model fits the requirement which uses openVPN setup. You can use a VPN client to connect to VMware Engine from your computer. You can download openVPN client for Windows or Viscosity for macOS and OS X.

Comment: Refer  [link](https://cloud.google.com/vmware-engine/docs/networking/howto-vpn-connect#connect-to-gcf-using-point-to-site-vpn) to know how to establish connection via VPN.
Refer to the [link](https://www.getloki.com/guides/openvpn/how-to-setup-an-openvpn-server-on-google-cloud-platform) to set up an openvpn server.

Comment: great thanks! this helps a lot.